# Converting Postgresql data to Open Street Maps

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap

I have some shapefiles that I tried to convert to .osm without success. After hours trying, I'm looking for a different approach. I wanna know if I can import from Postgres to Open Street Maps.

I'm really working hard for it but I'm not finding a way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with osmosis, this is an example to export from postgis to osm:

```
osmosis --read-apidb host="x" database="x" user="x" password="x" --write-xml file="planet.osm"
```

Here is an osmosis setup [HowTo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/PostGIS_Setup)